# How to modify/replace option set file when building from command line?

Tags: delphi, deployment, delphi-2009

I build packages from a batch file using commands like:

```
msbuild ..\lib\Package.dproj /target:Build /p:config=%1
```

The packages' settings are dependent on an option set:

```
<Import Project="..\optionsets\COND_Defined.optset" Condition="'$(Base)'!='' And Exists('..\optionsets\COND_Defined.optset')"/>
```

This option set defines a conditional symbol many of my packages depend on. The file looks like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DCC_Define>CONDITION;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectExtensions>
        <Borland.Personality>Delphi.Personality.12</Borland.Personality>
        <Borland.ProjectType>OptionSet</Borland.ProjectType>
        <BorlandProject>
            <Delphi.Personality/>
        </BorlandProject>
        <ProjectFileVersion>12</ProjectFileVersion>
    </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

Now I need two builds: one with the condition defined and one without. My attack vector would be the option set file. I have some ideas on what to do:

- write a program which modifies the option set file, run this before batch build
- fiddle with the project files and modify the option set path to contain an environment variable, then have different option sets in different locations

But before starting to reinvent the wheel I'd like to ask how you would tackle this task? Maybe there are already means meant to support such a case (like certain command line switches, things I could configure in Delphi or batch file magic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I approach this is to define multiple build configurations and then select the appropriate one at build time with `/p:config=XXX`. The works nicely in the IDE too because you can just double click the build config in the project manager to activate it.

I personally use inheritance of build configurations when I do this so that I don't have to repeat myself. For example I have a build configuration named `Debug DCUs` that inherits from the `Debug` configuration and simply changes the `Debug DCUs` option to `True`.

To help explain what I mean, here is what the build configuration tree looks like in my project:

[image]

The `Debug DCUs` configuration is effected by means of this option set:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DCC_DebugDCUs>true</DCC_DebugDCUs>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectExtensions>
        <Borland.Personality>Delphi.Personality.12</Borland.Personality>
        <Borland.ProjectType>OptionSet</Borland.ProjectType>
        <BorlandProject>
            <Delphi.Personality/>
        </BorlandProject>
        <ProjectFileVersion>12</ProjectFileVersion>
    </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

Now, I am sure that you could do this by using `/p:DCC_Define=XXX` but I think it is cleaner to use the build configurations so that you can be sure that what you get it the IDE is the same as what you get from the command line builds.

I would not recommend either approach in your bullet point list. Those approaches look exceedingly brittle to me.

Comment: The option set seemed to be a nice way to go even one level higher in the configuration hierarchy because I could at one place change the config for all dependent packages. But maybe it's not that big a difference compared to using the Configuration Manager.

Comment: Build configurations are fantastic for QA and repeatability. I love them! I still don't understand how to work them perfectly, but that's another story!!

Comment: Does this mean you don't modify anything directly in the Build Configurations (e.g. Debug) but rather define the settings in option sets which are added as reference? So the Build Configurations build the hierarchy and the option sets carry the settings?

Comment: Yes that is correct. That way I can share my option sets across all my various projects.

Comment: This solves the problem of inconsistent project settings once and for all! I really like it!

Comment: I had only one concern: the case where you have e.g. four different conditional symbols and need to combine them in different ways. I would have to create lots of Build Configurations, for every combination one. That made me think about option set generation. What do you think about this? Or is this a design failure anyway?

Comment: I agree that picking and choosing from a larger number of options rapidly gets unwieldy through build configs.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to temporarily rename the .optset file; this effectively disables it since the referenced file cannot be found. You can do it from your batch file before calling msbuild. This only works for option sets used as reference - as in your case.

Another option is to manually insert an `<Import>` directive in the `.dproj` file:

```
<Import Condition="Exists('$(OptSet)')" Project="$(OptSet)"/>
```

You can then set the `OptSet` property from the command line which will import the option set:

```
msbuild /t:Build /p:Config=Release /p:OptSet=myoptset.optset myproject.dproj
```

Without setting the `OptSet` property the option set will not be imported:

```
msbuild /t:Build /p:Config=Release myproject.dproj
```