# How to handle different per-project build configurations when doing automatic builds?

Tags: delphi, build-automation, delphi-2009

After diving deeper into [build configuration inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8315299/56658) the next question comes up: How do I handle build configurations which only exist for some packages?

The build from command line used to look like this:

```
msbuild ..\lib\Package1.dproj /target:Build /p:config=%1
msbuild ..\lib\Package2.dproj /target:Build /p:config=%1
msbuild ..\lib\Package3.dproj /target:Build /p:config=%1
```

Parameter `config` was either `Debug` or `Release`. This worked well.

Now some of the packages got new build configurations like `Release_Child_Config` (which inherits from `Release` in my case). I would now have to do (e.g.):

```
msbuild ..\lib\Package1.dproj /target:Build /p:config=Release_Child_Config
msbuild ..\lib\Package2.dproj /target:Build /p:config=Release_Child_Config
msbuild ..\lib\Package3.dproj /target:Build /p:config=Release
```

In this example `Package3` doesn't have a build configuration called `Release_Child_Config`. This means I cannot use one `config` parameter anymore.

I want all packages having the special build configuration `Release_Child_Config` to be built with it, the others should fall back to `Release`. Is it possible to automate this somehow? Or do I have to create each build configuration for each package?

Comment: What are you passing the batch script in `%1`?

Comment: You could use an if statement in your .bat file to convert Release into Release_Child_Config for the projects that want that. But it seems that you are making life hard for yourself. Why not stick to plain Release?

Comment: There are two different releases. The 'normal' release (`Release`) and the 'special' release (`Release_Child_Config`). The special one is 'normal' plus X. I need to be able to build them both automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use both configurations. If one is not enabled, build should be skipped:

```
msbuild ..\lib\Package1.dproj /target:Build /p:config="Release_Child_Config;Release"
msbuild ..\lib\Package2.dproj /target:Build /p:config="Release_Child_Config;Release"
msbuild ..\lib\Package3.dproj /target:Build /p:config="Release_Child_Config;Release"
```

or change config order to "Release;Release_Child_Config" (release will be build first)

Comment: Are you sure about this? The .dproj files have several checks for equality in them like `'$(Config)'=='Release'` and also the command line doc for msbuild hints that `Release_Child_Config;Release
` will be treated as a single value.

Comment: [It sholud work.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/msbuild/thread/b2c2808e-92a0-4866-8f73-3cc550d1c469) It should be internally treated as ItemList.

Comment: Hm, it does something, but not what I specify as `config`. Seems like it uses `Base`. My bet is that the .dproj file has to be prepared to handle such a list of values for a single param, but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Until something better comes up here is my interim solution: Generate the batch commands via script.

- Script input: list of projects to build
- Script output: batch file containing the build commands for each project

The script looks into each of the project files (.dproj) and does a simple string search. If it finds `Release_Child_Config` it writes this to the batch file:

```
  msbuild ..\lib\Package1.dproj /target:Build /p:config=Release_Child_Config
```

If not, it falls back to this:

```
  msbuild ..\lib\Package1.dproj /target:Build /p:config=Release
```

Of course the script does a bit more so it can also be used for similar cases of `Debug` and `Debug_Child_Config` etc. So far it does its job and fits into the build chain.